# Problem with a custom chapter definition and scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: chapters, scrlayer-scrpage

I have written a custom chapter command that uses *tikz* to draw a box for the title, add a picture and other stuff. So far everything works as expected, but the marking for the *chapter* of the headline is not updated. It stays the heading of the last conventional chapter, in my case `List of figures`. Is there an easy way to fix it?

### Code

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrhack}

\usepackage[twoside, margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\usepackage{xifthen}

\usepackage[headsepline=yes]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\ihead{\headmark}
\chead[]{}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ifoot[]{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ofoot[]{}

\newcommand{\mfc}[6][]%[short] title, pic, pic caption, lof caption, description
{ \cleardoublepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \refstepcounter{chapter}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#2}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [   overlay,
    remember picture
    ]
    \draw[rounded corners=5mm,thick] ($(current page text area.south west)!0.5!(current page text area.north west)$) rectangle ($(current page text area.south east)!0.6!(current page text area.north east)$);
    \node (c-\thechapter) at ($(current page text area.south west)!0.55!(current page text area.north west)+(1.5,0)$)  {\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont \textsf{\textbf{\thechapter}}};
    \draw[thick] ($(current page text area.south west)!0.5!(current page text area.north west)+(3,0)$) -- ($(current page text area.south west)!0.6!(current page text area.north west)+(3,0)$);
    \node[right,align=left,text width=12cm,font=\Huge] at ($(current page text area.south west)!0.55!(current page text area.north west)+(3.5,0)$) {#2};
    %\node[draw,line width=3mm,blue!50!gray,inner sep=0pt,rounded corners=2mm] at ($(current page text area.north east)+(-5,-5)$) {AAAAAARG};

    \begin{scope}[shift={($(current page text area.south west)!0.62!(current page text area.north west)+(6,0)$)}]
        #3
    \end{scope}
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#5}}
    {   \node[above right, text width=5.5cm, align=left] at ($(current page text area.south west)!0.62!(current page text area.north west)+(0,0)$)  {\captionof{figure}{#4}};
    }
    {   \node[above right, text width=5.5cm, align=left] at ($(current page text area.south west)!0.62!(current page text area.north west)+(0,0)$)  {\captionof{figure}[#5]{#4}};
    }

  \end{tikzpicture}

  \vspace{13cm}

    \begin{minipage}{0.97\textwidth}
        \begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}
            \hspace{1cm}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t][0.4\textheight]{0.87\textwidth}
            #6
        \end{minipage}  
    \end{minipage}
    \clearpage
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\foreach \c in {1,...,5}
{   \mfc{chapter \c}{\draw (0,0) rectangle (5,5) node[pos=0.5] {picture \c};}{pic \c caption}{lof \c caption}{Some description of chapter \c.}
    \lipsum[\c]
    \foreach \s in {1,...,3}
    {   \section{Section \s}
        \lipsum
    }
}

\end{document}
```

### Output

The text in the red box should be the chapter title, so "2 chapter 2" and not "List of figures". Click on the picture to see a larger version.

[image]

Comment: Add `\markboth{\chaptermarkformat #2}{}` after `\refstepcounter{chapter}`.

Comment: Or adapt the `\chapter` macro appropriately? I guess this is the obvious solution, so presumably you have some reason not to do it ...

Comment: @esdd: Works like a charm. Would you care to add this as an answer?

Comment: @cfr: I adapted the chapter macro to suit the need for a custom "fancy" look, but _couln't_ add the behaviour described above, that's why I asked this question. Or perhaps I don't understand the intention behind your comment?

Comment: More likely I don't really understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\mfc` macro does not set any marks for the page header. So you have to add something like

```
\markboth{\chaptermarkformat #2}{}
```

after `\refstepcounter{chapter}`.

---

Here is different suggestion that also works for chapter titles which are longer than one line. And it is also possible to use the optional argument for a short title in TOC and/or header.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}% scalable font

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#2}{}
    {\@hangfrom{#2}{#3}}% normal format for unnumbered chapters
    {\mfc{#2}{#3}}% special format for numbered chapters
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\chapterformat{\thechapter}

\newcommand{\mfc}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
      overlay,
      remember picture,
      thick
    ]
    \path
      (current page text area.north west)++(0,-.4\textheight)
      node[
          minimum height=.1\textheight,
          minimum width=3cm,
          anchor=north west,
          font=\normalfont\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont\bfseries
        ](mfcnr)
        {#1}% chapter number
    ;
    \node[
        minimum height=.1\textheight,
        text width=12cm,
        align=left,
        right=.5cm,
        anchor=west,
        font=\normalfont\Huge
      ](mfctitle)
      at (mfcnr.east)
      {#2}% chapter title
    ;
    \draw(mfcnr.east|-mfctitle.north)--(mfcnr.east|-mfctitle.south);
    \draw[rounded corners=5mm]
      (mfcnr.west|-mfctitle.south)
      rectangle % border
      (\textwidth-\pgflinewidth,0|-mfctitle.north)
    ;
    \node[anchor=south west]
      at ([shift={(6,.02\textheight)}]mfcnr.west|-mfctitle.north)
      {\mfcpicture}% chapter picture
    ;
    \node[
        anchor=south west,
        text width=5.5cm,
        align=left
      ]
      at ([yshift=.02\textheight]mfcnr.west|-mfctitle.north)
      {%
        %\setcapindent{0pt}
        \mfccaption% chapter picture caption
      }
    ;
    \path
      (mfcnr.west|-mfctitle.south)
      ++(1cm,-\normalbaselineskip)
      node[
          anchor=north west,
          inner sep=0pt,
          node font=\normalfont\normalsize
        ]
        {%
          \begin{minipage}[t]{.87\textwidth}
          \mfcdescription% chapter descriptionh
          \end{minipage}%
        }
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  % reset picture and description
  \global\renewcommand\mfcpicture{}%
  \global\renewcommand\mfccaption{}%
  \global\renewcommand\mfcdescription{}%
  \clearpage
}

\newcommand\mfcpicture{}
\newcommand\setmfcpicture[1]{\renewcommand\mfcpicture{#1}}

\newcommand\mfccaption{}
\newcommand\mfccaptiontest{}
\newcommand\setmfccaption[2][\mfccaptiontest]{%
  \edef\mfccaptiontest{#2}
  \ifstr{#1}{\mfccaptiontest}
  {\renewcommand\mfccaption{\captionof{figure}[#2]{\raggedright #2}}}
  {\renewcommand\mfccaption{\captionof{figure}[#1]{\raggedright #2}}}%
}

\newcommand\mfcdescription{}
\newcommand\setmfcdescription[1]{\renewcommand\mfcdescription{#1}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\foreach \c in {1,...,5}
  {% chapters with pictures, captions and descriptions
    \setmfcpicture{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}
    \setmfccaption[LOF entry for picture \c]{Caption for picture \c}
    \setmfcdescription{Some description of chapter \c.\par \lipsum[1]}
    \chapter{Chapter \c}
    % some contents for the chapters
      \lipsum[\c]
      \foreach \s in {1,...,3}{\section{Section \s}\lipsum}
  }

\setmfcpicture{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-A}}
\setmfccaption{example}
\setmfcdescription{Test for a long chapter title with short entry in TOC and headings.}
\chapter[Short TOC and header entry]{A chapter with a long, long, long title that needs more than one line}

\section{A section}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]