# Geometry per section level?

Tags: margins, koma-script, geometry

Is it possible to have different geometries on different section levels, assuming always that you can guarantee they are on different pages. It may sound weird, but let me illustrate with a case where it should be obvious the need.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[outer=7cm, inner=3cm, marginparwidth=4cm, marginparsep=10mm, showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
  \part{test}
\end{document}
```

In this example of a document that uses wide margin notes, the part pages would be separators between chapters, and I would expect to have those pages centered differently from the main pages (i.e. centered to paper, and therefore with a geometry without margins)

[image]

I understan I could \newgeometry and \restoregeometry every time, but I would expect I could associate it with \part{} and get it done automatically.
Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: For a single page you could just ignore/overlay the margins.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311992/problem-with-a-custom-chapter-definition-and-scrlayer-scrpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[outer=7cm, inner=3cm, marginparwidth=4cm, marginparsep=10mm, showframe]{geometry}
\let\oldpart\part
\def\part#1{\newgeometry{marginparwidth=0cm,marginparsep=0cm,showframe,inner=0cm,outer=0cm}\oldpart{#1}\restoregeometry}
\begin{document}
  \part{test}
  \chapter{Test}
  \lipsum[1-3]
  \part{test}
  \chapter{Test}
  \lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Just test it and change it to your needs... 
PS: I don't think that a screenshot is needed.

Comment: Nice idea but please try `\part[Detest]{test}` with and without your redefinition of `\part`. You may want to use something like `titlesec` to patch the command.

Comment: @marmot ... it can be solved with this way: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394571/120578 but is too rare (the optional argument inside part) and I don't want to make it so complicated here without a reason ... If the OP will ask something like that (s)he can find it on this link ... or can ask me to change all `section`s to `part`s in that code. Thanks although about the useful comment

Comment: @koleygr With `xparse`, redefining the sectioning commands in a way that handles all variants can be done with little pain (clearly less than in the link you gave), see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499081/how-do-i-get-the-first-page-number-of-the-currect-chapter-section/499132#499132) for an example by egreg.

Answer (score 0):

You can patch the section level command to change the geometry:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\part
  {\newgeometry{marginparwidth=0cm,marginparsep=0cm,showframe,inner=0cm,outer=0cm}}
  {}{\PatchFailedI}
```

If a section level puts its headings on an own page, then it is a part like section level with  `style=part` (option of `\DeclareSectionCommand` etc, see the documentation). You can patch `\partheademptypage` to restore the geometry after all section levels using `style=part`. This works also for `\addpart` and the starred versions. Additionally the optional argument of `\part` can be used.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[outer=7cm, inner=3cm, marginparwidth=4cm, marginparsep=10mm, showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\part
  {\newgeometry{marginparwidth=0cm,marginparsep=0cm,showframe,inner=0cm,outer=0cm}}
  {}{\PatchFailedI}
\xapptocmd\partheademptypage
  {\restoregeometry}
  {}{\PatchFailedII}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{test}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1-3]
\addpart{test}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1-3]
\part[toc entry]{title}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

If you want to do the same for chapters, change the `style` option to part and patch `\chapter`:

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  style=part,
]{chapter}
\xpretocmd\chapter
  {\newgeometry{marginparwidth=0cm,marginparsep=0cm,showframe,inner=0cm,outer=0cm}}
  {}{\PatchFailedIII}
```

---

Starting with version 3.27 KOMA-Script will provide new Hooks (DoHooks). At the moment you need the prerelease of 3.27 ([available on the KOMA-Script website](https://komascript.de/node/1801)) to test the following example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}[2019/07/29]% needs prerelease 3.27.3193 or newer
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[outer=7cm, inner=3cm, marginparwidth=4cm, marginparsep=10mm, showframe]{geometry}

\AddtoDoHook{heading/postinit/part}{\partgeometry}
\newcommand*\partgeometry[1]
  {\newgeometry{marginparwidth=0cm,marginparsep=0cm,showframe,inner=0cm,outer=0cm}}
\let\originalpartheademptypage\partheademptypage
\renewcommand\partheademptypage
  {\originalpartheademptypage\restoregeometry}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{test}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1-3]
\addpart{test}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1-3]
\part[toc entry]{title}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```